# Button listener in LibGDX

Tags: android, button, libgdx

I have nearly 100 buttons in my screen. Do I need to do the same for those 100 buttons or is there is any simple way to achieve this. Pelase advice

```
button1.addListener(new InputListener() {
public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        Gdx.app.log("my app", "Pressed"); //** Usually used to start Game, etc. **//
        return true;
}

public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        Gdx.app.log("my app", "Released");
}
```

Comment: If they have the same behaviour you could just create 1 listener and add it to all those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**//Add Variable Class:**

```
ArrayList<Button> buttonArray = ArrayList<Button>();

InputListener inputListener;
```

In Your code add in show for example:

**//in Your Code:**

```
    inputListener = new InputListener() {

        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, 
                                  int pointer, int button) {

            //** Usually used to start Game, etc. **//
            Gdx.app.log("my app", "Pressed"); 
            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, 
                             int pointer, int button) {

            Gdx.app.log("my app", "Released");
        } 

    };
```

**//in Your Code:**

```
buttonArray.add(button1);
buttonArray.add(button2);
buttonArray.add(button3);

for(int a = 0; a < buttonArray.size(); a++){
    buttonArray.get(a).addListener(inputListener);
}
```

it wont test in Ide now, but I think you can help.

**NEW**

I did not know you wanted to know which button is pressed, so that you can make some changes, you add it to the response, but not if it will be the best way.

**//Add Variable Class:**

```
ArrayList<Button> buttonArray = ArrayList<Button>();
```

**//Add in your Class:**

```
private class TestInputListenerOverflow extends InputListener{

    int id;

    public TestInputListenerOverflow (int hashCode){
        this.id = hashCode;
    }
    public void setButtonId(int hashCode){
        this.id = hashCode;
    }
    public int getButtonId(){
        return id;
    }
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, 
            int pointer, int button) {

        //** Usually used to start Game, etc. **//

        if(button1.hashCode() == id){
            Gdx.app.log("my app", "Pressed");
            Gdx.app.log("my app", "You Pressed button1");
        }else if(button2.hashCode() == id){
            Gdx.app.log("my app", "Pressed");
            Gdx.app.log("my app", "You Pressed button2");
        }else if(button3.hashCode() == id){
            Gdx.app.log("my app", "Pressed");
            Gdx.app.log("my app", "You Pressed button3");
        }else if(button4.hashCode() == id){
            Gdx.app.log("my app", "Pressed");
            Gdx.app.log("my app", "You Pressed button4");
        }else if(button5.hashCode() == id){
            Gdx.app.log("my app", "Pressed");
            Gdx.app.log("my app", "You Pressed button5");
        }

        return true;
        }

        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, 
                       int pointer, int button) {

        Gdx.app.log("my app", "Released");
        } 
}
```

**//in Your Code:**

```
buttonArray.add(button1); 
buttonArray.add(button2);
buttonArray.add(button3);
buttonArray.add(button4);
buttonArray.add(button5);

for(int a = 0; a < buttonArray.size(); a++){
    buttonArray.get(a).addListener(
                        new TestInputListenerOverflow(
                        buttonArray.get(a).hashCode())
                        );
}
```

Comment: Code looks clean. But how does it knows that which button is pressed. I hope we have to check the coordinates again